# Pandas change date time format to only month

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

My Datamframe Date columns has the datetime64[ns] type. it contains date in '%YYYY-%MM-%DD %MM:%SS:%NN. How can I change it to only show the month?

Comment: `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m')` or `df['Date'].dt.month`?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_col': ['2022-01-01 12:34:56', '2022-02-01 23:45:12', '2022-03-01 03:45:56']})
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_col']).dt.strftime('%m')
print(df)
```

which is

```
          datetime_col month
0  2022-01-01 12:34:56    01
1  2022-02-01 23:45:12    02
2  2022-03-01 03:45:56    03
```